# Extract two properties of a List<T> using LINQ in C#

Tags: c#, linq, list

I have a list of `Line` classes. How can I extract the `P1` and `P2` properties of all the lines into `Points<Point>` list using LINQ?

```
public class Line
{
    public Point P1;
    public Point P2;
}

var points = Lines.Select()?
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There are many ways.

You can use `SelectMany` like this:

```
var points = lines.SelectMany(x => new[] {x.P1,x.P2}).ToList();
```

Or you can use `Concat` like this:

```
var points = lines.Select(x => x.P1).Concat(lines.Select(x => x.P2)).ToList();
```

Please note that the first version enumerates the list only once (which is better), while the second version does it twice.

Comment: did you mean `lines.Select(x =>  new[] {x.P1,x.P2}).SelectMany(y =>y).ToList()` ?

Comment: Is there a difference?

Comment: haven't actually tried compiling but doesn't your first version create a list of anon objects?

Comment: No. It creates an array of two elements.

Comment: It is the same as `new Point[]{...`

Answer (score 2):

You can use [AddRange](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/z883w3dc(v=vs.110).aspx)

```
var points = Lines.Select(x=>x.P1).ToList();
points.AddRange(Lines.Select(x=>x.P2));
```